# Merging MultiDiemensional array

Tags: php

I have an array like,

```
 $arr = array( 
    array(           
       'ID'=>1,
       'SCREEN'=>'HOME',
       'EN'=>'Home'
     ),
     array(
        'ID'=>1,
        'SCREEN'=>'HOME',
        'RU'=>'RU-HOME'
     ),
     array(
        'ID'=>1,
        'SCREEN'=>'LOGIN',
        'EN'=>'Home'
     )
   );
```

How can i get something like this,

```
 $arr = array(
  array(
   'ID'=>1,
   'SCREEN'=>'HOME',
   'EN'=>'Home',
   'RU'=>'RU-HOME'
   ),
  array(
   'ID'=>1,
   'SCREEN'=>'LOGIN',
   'EN'=>'Home'
  )
);
```

Comment: Uugh... =_=;; Spot the difference...?

Comment: Write code to do it! :)

Comment: Loop over your sub arrays, creating a new array.  The keys of the new array will be the ID from each sub array.  If you haven't already got the ID key in the new array, you assign the sub array to the new array using ID as key.  If you have got the ID in the new array, then you just add the new values to the existing array for the ID key.  Good luck learning programming.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of answering the question, even though it makes little sense

```
 array(
 array_merge(
    array(
     'ID'=>1,
     'SCREEN'=>
     'HOME',
     'EN'=>'Home'
    ),
    array(
     'ID'=>1,
     'SCREEN'=>
     'HOME',
    'RU'=>'RU-HOME'
    )
  ),
 array(
   'ID'=>1,
   'SCREEN'=>'LOGIN',
   'EN'=>'Home'
 )
);
```